# WP shortcode pass variable to function

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I'm trying to pass or store a file path string which the CMS user provides in the shortcode, and use this in a function which is then executed when the short code has rendered.

**Here are the details:**

```
function wpsdc( $atts ) {
extract( shortcode_atts( array(
    'file_path' => '', 
    'text' => ''
    ), $atts ) );

$wpsdc_output = wpsdc_short_code($text);

return $wpsdc_output;
}
add_shortcode('wpsdc','wpsdc');
```

My **wpsdc_short_code** function returns some basic form html:

```
<form action='wpsdc-validate-email.php' method='post' id='download_content'>
   <input id='emailtext' name='email' type='text'>
   <button id='submit-email' type='submit'>Click</button>
</form>
```

What I am aiming to do is return a string (which I render as an anchor text link) to the file path defined in the initial short code.

```
[wpsdc file_path='/downloads/some_pdf_file.pdf' text='Click']
```

How therefore do I get the $file_path variable to my '**wpsdc-validate-email.php**' file WITHOUT having the file string visible in the html form mark-up?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see a few approaches to this:

1. Use php's `mcrypt` functions to encrypt your `file_path` and store it in a hidden field on the form, then use `mcrypt_decrypt` to decode it in your form action script. Documentation here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php
2. Store the `file_path` in a php `$_SESSION` and use this. See this Wordpress support thread for the basics: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/using-session-in-wordpress
3. You could also use a plugin like [WP Session Manager](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-session-manager/) in the event that your PHP server is locked down.

Comment: Thank you! Better answer than I could have hoped for :-)